# User Mapping between my system and Docusign User

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

A customer has a DocuSign account with Multiple user, They want to Map it with user in my ERP System, so that when the user send the document to Docusign(using Soap API), the Signer should see the information(email id) of respective User. How can we achieve this?

Comment: do you already have an existing integration that was built?

Comment: I'm asking cause SOAP API has an old feature called SOBO to do this, but this legacy feature is not a secure/recommended way. If you are going to build your integration using REST And OAuth - the answer is different.

Answer (score 0):

Each user in the DocuSign system has a unique user ID (userId) that is a GUID value that uniquely identifies them.
This value can be stored in the ERP system in relation to the user in that system.
This way, when you make API calls to DocuSign, you can use this identifier to ensure the call is made in the context of the user your ERP system gives you so that the mapping works.

This method can also be used to add a new user if one doesn't yet exist in the DocuSign account that is used by the system. There's an API that does this.